# Problem in Executing Bat file for Ant Jar build

Tags: file, jar, ant

Unable to Execute The Bat file for building jar and copying into different location.

```
 C:\apache-ant-1.9.15\bin\ant -f build.xml && COPY Source-Folder-Path Destination-Folder-Path /y
```

Its not building jar file. Can you pls rectify my script. I am using bat file to do this as its my regular task in project.

Comment: What are the actual error messages you get?

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash?

Comment: @DuncG Getting build success but not getting the jar on the location. So i  wanna know that to build jar using ant this command is right or not

Comment: @RamanSailopal I thought bash is system where u run script file so add that tag. I will remove that tag if its not appropriate. Thanks

Comment: Try `@echo on` at start of your bat file, and add `-verbose` flag to ant command. This may tell you why the jar is not being built.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and would like to post here for someone else, who got stuck here.

- Write this script and put it near build.xml
- Run the bat file in command line for repeat process.

```
C:\apache-ant-1.9.15\bin\ant compile jar  && COPY D:\karshil-sheth\java.jar C:\my-Project\webapp\WEB-INF\lib /y
```

Script Explanation :-

- It will find ant from location u installed or can write simple ant.
- compile jar will create jar and put in the folder where u running the bat.
- Also can write `ant compile jar run` this script and run, will get same output.
- after && I am copying file from source to destination path as every time I change the code project will be executed from that jar.
- /y is for overriding the last jar and pop up wont appear every time you run this script.